# Question about Purging Nvidia Driver

Tags: nvidia, purge

Does purging Nvidia driver on Ubuntu also purges the driver from the windows? I'm using a dual-boot in my system and I don't know if it will affect the other os or not. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, purging Nvidia driver from Ubuntu doesn't purge it from windows.

Although you are dual booting, Ubuntu and windows, they both are separate entities, in separate partitions.

Answer (score 0):

No. They separate drivers on separate systems, so when you purge the Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu it will leave windows drivers intact.